# use io hook to move puppteer's mouse

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

Is it possible to make a puppeteer's cursor hold the mouse down button (to draw or drag.) when I hold my left mouse button down? and at the same location?

I did something using IoHook.

```
    ioHook.on("mouseclick", event => {
//console.log(event.x);
/* You get object like this
{
  type: 'mousemove',
  x: 700,
  y: 400
}
*/
var x = event.x
var y = event.y - 71
page.mouse.click(x, y, { button: 'left' })
});


ioHook.on("mousemove", event => {
//console.log(event.x);
/* You get object like this
{
  type: 'mousemove',
  x: 700,
  y: 400
}
*/
var x = event.x
var y = event.y - 71
page.mouse.move(x, y)
});
```

this piece of code follows my mouse, and clicks where I click, but it doesn't hold the left mouse button down and moves where i move. So i want to pull off like a basic on mouse down follow the mouse's cursor.

page.mouse.click(x, y, { button: 'left' }) is being used for the puppeteer's cursor.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In puppeteer documentation website:

https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=v2.0.0&show=api-class-mouse

> Using ‘page.mouse’ to trace a 100x100 square.
>
> ```
> await page.mouse.move(0, 0);
> await page.mouse.down();
> await page.mouse.move(0, 100);
> await page.mouse.move(100, 100);
> await page.mouse.move(100, 0);
> await page.mouse.move(0, 0);
> await page.mouse.up();
> ```

So to make mouse drag, you've to put some `await page.mouse.move()` after an `await page.mouse.down()` and before an `await page.mouse.up()`

`page.mouse.click()` is a combination of two event `mouse.down()` and `mouse.up()` in same position on a very short time delay.

And in IOHook documentation:
https://wilix-team.github.io/iohook/usage.html#mousedrag

> Triggered when user clicks and drags something.
>
> ```
> { button: 0, clicks: 0, x: 373, y: 683, type: 'mousedrag' }
> ```

So the solution here is, you have to listen the mousedrag event.

Answer (score 0):

Solution. Added the mousedrag event.

```
ioHook.on("mousedrag", event => {
var x = event.x
var y = event.y - 71
console.log( "mouseDRAG!!!" + event)
page.mouse.move(x, y);
});


ioHook.on("mousemove", event => {
var x = event.x
var y = event.y - 71
console.log( "mousemove!!!" + event)
page.mouse.move(x, y);
});


ioHook.on("mousedown", event => {
var x = event.x
var y = event.y - 71
console.log( "mousedown!!!" + event)
page.mouse.down();
});

ioHook.on("mouseup", event => {
var x = event.x
var y = event.y - 71
console.log( "mouseup!!!" + event)
page.mouse.up();
});
```